# Undefined reference error in overriding virtual functions in c++

Tags: c++, overriding

I'm actually new to c++. I mostly worked with Java.
I tried to build my own iterator, and after a bit of reading, came up with this method.

```
template<class T> class Iterable
    {
        T start,stop;
    public:
        explicit Iterable(T s,T e) {start=s; stop=e;}


    public:
        virtual void next(T& i);
    public:
        class iterator: public std::iterator<
        std::input_iterator_tag,   // iterator_category
        T,                      // value_type
        long,                      // difference_type
        const T*,               // pointer
        T                       // reference
        >{
            T current;
            Iterable<T>& obj;
        public:
            explicit iterator(T t,Iterable<T>& o) : obj(o) {current=t;}
            iterator& operator++() {obj.next(current); return *this;}
            iterator operator++(int) {iterator retval = *this; ++(*this); return retval;}
            bool operator==(iterator other) const {return current == other.current;}
            bool operator!=(iterator other) const {return !(*this == other);}
            T operator*() const {return current;}
        };
        iterator begin() {return iterator(start,*this);}
        iterator end() {return iterator(stop,*this);}
    };
    class Range : public Iterable<long>
    {
        long START,STOP;
    public:
        void next(long& cur) override
        {
            if(START>=STOP)
                cur++;
            else
                cur--;
        }
    public:
        Range(long st,long en) : Iterable(st,en) {START=st; STOP=en;}

    };
```

This is my "flex.h" header file. The header compiles OK.
However, when I try to use this Range class, I get the error:

```
undefined reference to `flex::Iterable<long>::next(long&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

in my compiler (I use g++)
My Test1.cpp file is as follows:

```
(After includes)
int main()
{
    Range range=Range(15,10);
    for(auto r : range)
        cout << r << "\n";
}
```

Could someone explain where I went wrong, and how this can be fixed?
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You declare a virtual function in `next`, and don't define it.

A virtual member function has to be defined, be pure virtual, or both. So if you declare

```
virtual void next(T& i);
```

It must be defined either inline or outside the class definition because it is not pure virtual. If you intended to make `Iterable` a template for abstract classes, then adding the pure virtual specifier to `next` will absolve the error.

```
virtual void next(T& i) = 0;
```

Comment: Works. Thanks a lot, but I didn't understand the explanation why.

Comment: @SreyasAdury - Clearer now?

Comment: Yes. Thank you for the clarification.